# Can you have a timer for SQL or PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

So i've found options but they're not suitable. Im currently making a PHP browser game which uses an SQL server.

Im trying to figure out a way for when the button is pressed, after 300 seconds an SQL cell should update and during the 300 seconds for it to be displayed on screen. Doesn't have to be a count down, even whats left.

Figuring out a way to do the 300 seconds and have it displayed when refreshed is what im having trouble with.

Comment: Maybe triggers can help you out on this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107175/how-can-i-run-a-sql-job-every-1-second

Comment: You would normally do something like this with Javascript and AJAX. Javascript does have [perfectly working timers](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-timers.php).

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesnt exist really, not in 'standard' code. You can aproach it some other way though:

On click you update the database, you set an eg `timerReady` to NOW()+300sec.

On refresh/reload/cron/whatever you check if `timerReady < NOW()`, then you know the 300sec have past. Otherwise, `timerReady - NOW()` is the amount of second remaining.

When you press the button you let javascript wait 300sec (I do recommend a timer/indicator) and then reload. And when the user reloads in the meantime, you can use the `timerReady - NOW()` trick to decide how long the user has to wait still.

You can do this with Javascript only, but if you do not store it in the database, when a user refreshes they must start over as you have no way of verifying anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with the potential problems that may arise if the user closes your application's browser tab, your best option would be a JavaScript snippet to do it:

1. When the user clicks the button, lunch a JavaScript timeout like this

   ```
   // 1. prepare timeout
   setTimeout(on_timeout_fn, 300000);
   ```

   What this piece of code does is, after 300 seconds, it will call `on_timeout_fn` function.
2. When time is up, your function `on_timeout_fn` will execute. You should define it to something like this:

   ```
   let on_timeout_fn = function() {
       // 2. run an ajax call to execute a PHP script that will update the database
       // if you're using something like JQuery, it should be as easy as:
       $.post("update_db.php", "data_to_send", function() {
           // 3. when ajax call ends, make sure the button dissapears
           $("#yourButtonID").toggle();
       }, "text");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well you would have to do this with JavaScript, and PHP. You can also use JQuery to do this feature. In Javascript you would grab the button on by its query selector wether that be an class or id by clicking and then you could set an a timer to where it won't execute the code until 300 seconds, then it runs the code sends the value to the back end by AJAX, fetch whatever you prefer. Then proceeds to use use PHP and MYSQL to update the data.